# Segfault occuring in attempt to synchronize queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, data-race

I am learning about multithreading and I wanted to simulate producer-consumer problem ( using semaphore if I can call it that ).

I have a class that holds a queue, producer push ints into queue and consumer retrieves it and prints it. I simulated is as following

```
class TestClass{
public:
    void producer( int i ){
        unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
        q.push(i);
        if( q.size() )
            cnd.notify_all();
    }

    void consumer(){
        unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
        while( q.empty() ){
            cnd.wait(l);
        }
        int tmp = q.front();
        q.pop();
        cout << "Producer got " << tmp << endl;
    }
    void ConsumerInit( int threads ){
        for( int i = 0; i < threads; i++ ){
            thrs[i] = thread(&TestClass::consumer, this );
        }
        for( auto &a : thrs )
            a.join();
    }


private:
    queue<int> q;
    vector<thread> thrs;
    mutex m;
    condition_variable cnd;
};
```

And I used a little console application to call data:

```
int main(){
    int x;   
    TestClass t;
    int counter = 0;
    while( cin >> x ){
        if( x == 0 )
            break;
        if( x == 1)
            t.producer(counter++);
        if( x == 2 )
            t.ConsumerInit(5);
    }   
}
```

So when user input 1, a data is pushed into the queue , if user press 2 threads are spawned.

In any order of invoking it, for example, pressing 1 1 and then 2, or 2 1 1
it throws segfault. I am not sure why my understanding of my code is as following: let's assume order 2 1 1

I initialize 5 threads, they see that queue is empty, so they go to sleep. When I push a number to the queue, it notifies all threads sleeping.
The first one to wake up lock mutex again and proceed to retrieve number from queue and afterwards releasing the mutex, when mutex is released another thread do the same and unlocks the mutex, the third thread after mutex is unlocked is still in loop and see that queue is yet again empty and goes to sleep again, same with all remaining threads.

Is this logic correct? If so, why does this keep throwing segfault, if not, I appreciate all explanations.

Thanks for the help!

//edit 
By answers suggets , i replaced [] with vector.push_back , but consumer does nothing with data now , does not take it or print it.

Comment: typo, thanks! updated it

Comment: oh , thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't expanding the thrs vector when you do

```
thrs[i] = thread(&CTest::consumer, this );
```

You should do

```
thrs.emplace_back(&CTest::consumer, this);
```

That's where the crash would be.

Comment: noticed it and added push_back , but the consumer does nothing with data now , it does not take it and print it.

Comment: ConsumerInit will block indefinitely if there aren't 5 inputs waiting (and therefore the program can't do any more input).  Are you inputting "2 1 1" ?

Comment: users inpu is 2 1 1 , so it creates threads , and then push number in queue twice

Comment: It creates 5 threads and then waits for them to terminate, then inputs another number.

Comment: I see your point , however when i remove join() and input 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 , the 5 numbers are printed , cuz thred takes them , but how could i make them to print all numbers , in this case alll 6 of them , and after joining them , termiante threads when queue is empty?

Comment: @trolkura Input the data one by one instead of a single line.  That will slow down things enough for you to see that consumer() is just sitting there in a wait state and producer() is never called.  As a matter of fact, the loop in `main()` never iterates to the top for any input after the first one (run in Visual Studio 2015).  Looks like you are relying on "speed", and not safeness.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with multithreading.  You are accessing a `std::vector` out-of-bounds:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        thrs[i] = thread(&CTest::consumer, this);

  //...
  vector<thread> thrs;
```

The `thrs` vector is empty, and you're trying to access as if it has entries.

To show the error, use:

```
        thrs.at(i) = thread(&CTest::consumer, this);
```

and you will be greeted with a `std::out_of_range` exception instead of a segmentation fault.

Comment: noticed it and added push_back , but the consumer does nothing with data now , it does not take it and print it.

Comment: Then that is another issue altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Your program deadlocks, if the input sequence is not in the form of `1 1 1 1 1 ... 2`. That is if the number if `1s` preceding `2` is less than five.

Here is the reason:

If the total elements in queue size are less than 5 and the main thread calls `consumerInit`, some of the five created consumer threads will block waiting for the queue to receive elements. Meanwhile, the main thread blocks on the `join` operation. Since the main thread will be waiting for consumer threads to finish while some of those threads are waiting for data to consume, there will be no progress. Hence deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
  for( auto &a : thrs )
        a.join();
```

Main thread gets blocked here after you enter `2` waiting for the consumers to finish. So after this point you think that you are entering inputs, while there is no `cin` happening.

Remove these two lines and then you can enter `1` and producer/consumer will do their job.